# Grant Use-STSRole (sts:AssumeRole) permission to any CodeBuild project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codebuild, aws-powershell

I have several AWS CodeBuild projects that use [`Use-STSRole`](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/powershell/latest/reference/items/Use-STSRole.html) to [Assume Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) of a more privlidged role (`readwrite`) in order to then read a secret from Secrets Manager.

I have configured the `readwrite` role's Trust Relationship as:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [    
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

When my CodeBuild project runs I get an error:

```
Use-STSRole: C:\example-stack-overflow-question\common\utility.psm1:6
Line |
   6 |      Use-STSRole -RoleArn $RoleArn -RoleSessionName $RoleSessionName | …
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | User:
     | arn:aws:sts::112233445566:assumed-role/aws-lambda-dotnet-powershe-SignProjectRole5EF6D320-X2IF2P0P1J4/AWSCodeBuild-0d189fc5-f3b6-440a-bed6-ab54ed5f6c08 
     | is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/readwrite
```

**How can I configure my IAM role `readwrite` to allow any CodeBuild project to Assume that Role via `Use-STSRole`?**

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the restriction for just codebuild to work.  Instead I ended up allowing the `AssumeRole` action to anything in my account:

```json
   {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
```

So now my CodeBuild projects can use the `Use-STSRole` cmdlet

Comment: Did you add that action to a Trust policy? Was it on your user or a service role? I have a similar issue trying to get what is described in this article working. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/codebuild-temporary-credentials-docker/